# Nested attributes text field isn't showing up in my views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, web

I am new to the rails community. I am working on an application where users can have username with a nested attribute of first and last name. The other text field associated with the User model works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Attached are the app models, controllers, migration files, db schema, and views.

**models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :username, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :username, allow_destroy: true

end


class Username < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user


end
```

**Migrations**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :about_me
      t.string :nationality
      t.string :sexe
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


class CreateUsernames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :usernames do |t|
      add_column :username, :first_name, :string
      add_column :username, :last_name, :string
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @all_users = User.all
    @new_user = User.new
    @username = Username.new
  end

  def new
    @new_user = User.new
  end

  def create
    User.create(user_params)
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :about_me, username_attributes:
    [:last_name, :first_name])
  end
end
```

**Views**

```
<h1>Users#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/index.html.erb</p>


<%= form_for @new_user do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for @new_user do |user| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= user.label :email%>
      <%= user.text_field :email %>
      <%= user.label :about_me %>
      <%= user.text_field :about_me %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.fields_for :username do |name| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= name.label :first_name %>
        <%= name.text_field :first_name %>
      </div>
    <% end %>


     <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit %>
      </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: could you try `f.fields_for :username, @new_user.username do |name|`

Comment: still isn't showing the first name field

Answer (score 0):

Try this
controller

```
def new
    @new_user = User.new
    @new_user.usernames.build
end
```

view

```
<%= form_for @new_user do |f| %>
  # ...
  <%= f.fields_for :usernames do |name| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= name.label :first_name %>
      <%= name.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

helper

```
def name_format(user_mst)
    name = user_mst.first_name.capitalize
    name += (" #{user_mst.last_name.capitalize}")

    return name
end
```

to display on view

Comment: This is what the console returned                                                           undefined method `usernames' for #<User:0x007fbd26380280>                            
9
10
11
12
13
              
  def new
      @new_user = User.new
      @new_user.usernames.build
  end

Comment: do you have user_id as field on your username table?

Comment: no I don't I thought that's what has_one and belongs to was for

Comment: So you mean that the relation is one to one? if that is the case why not put the username as field of your user table

Comment: no.  the relation is user have one username whos attributes are first and last name. I just want to be able call out user.username in the views which would display first and last name combined.

Comment: Why not put those fields on your user table then you can format it on your model or helper

Comment: I don't know how to do that.do you mean to  have a first and a last name column be a reference  attribute of user model?

Comment: Just add last_name and first_name field for your database user table

Comment: how would I combine both column  in order to display the username

Comment: @KrisChery see the updated answer if its what you are looking